# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tc.sol.wf.base.interfaces.ISolutionWorflow

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, war

I am trying to deploy a WAR file on my server (Ubuntu 12.0.4) - When I paste it in my tomcat7's webapps folder and deploy it, I get an error HTTP status 404 i.e. resource not found. I tried deploying the same WAR file through my manager application, it throws a ClassNotFoundException for a class that is definitely present in a JAR in the lib folder.
Project uses a web servlet 3.0, so the web.xml is empty.

Note - this is the first time I am posting a question here, not sure what parts of the project I can share to help make my situation more clear.

EDIT -

```
type Exception report

message com/tc/sol/wf/base/interfaces/ISolutionWorflow

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tc/sol/wf/base/interfaces/ISolutionWorflow
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2959)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1212)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1692)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tc.sol.wf.base.interfaces.ISolutionWorflow
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1722)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2959)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1212)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1692)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1573)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved adding the missing libs to the manifest file as classpath. I believe so someother jar is calling this class file ,so manifest entry will help out.